# How to Query a JSON file using Angular/Ionic?

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to have Angular query a JSON file instead of using an http request in an Ionic project.

I'm working with the Ionic tutorial found here: https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/index.html

I have gone through the entire tutorial and am "tinkering" which started with me wanting to change the data source from being an http request to a local JSON file and I've been partially successful.

All of the code I have in the project matches exactly what's seen in the tutorial with the following exception.

In the tutorial on "Module 4: Creating the Session Service," I changed this block seen in Step 3:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:5000/sessions/:sessionId');
});
```

To be:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('data/sessions.json');
});
```

To create the JSON file I took the return value of the http request seen in the tutorial and pasted it into the file referenced in the code and it is valid JSON.

Now, when I run the project (in a desktop browser or emulator), I am able to see the list of Sessions that was read from the JSON as expected. However, when I click/tap one of the Sessions to see the detail, the UI appears but has no data. When using the original code that gets the data via http I can see the detail.

This is the controller in my code that matches the tutorial, which presumably is where the problem lies:

```
.controller('SessionCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Session) {
    $scope.session = Session.get({sessionId: $stateParams.sessionId});
})
```

Here is the HTML for that view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Session">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>{{session.time}}</h3>
        <h2>{{session.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{session.speaker}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <p>{{session.description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
        <a class="tab-item">
          <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i>
          Like
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item">
          <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
          Comment
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item">
          <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
          Share
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the error in the console after clicking through to the Session detail view:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] get
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8762:12)
    at d.module.provider.$get.e.(anonymous function).q.then.p.$resolved (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js:9:330)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21888:27)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21904:27
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23100:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22916:31)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23205:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18358:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18548:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18489:9)
```

And here's the data where the Session list comes from and it's also the data I want to query:

```
[{"id":0,"title":"Introduction to Ionic","speaker":"CHRISTOPHE COENRAETS","time":"9:40am","room":"Ballroom A","description":"In this session, you'll learn how to build a native-like mobile application using the Ionic Framework, AngularJS, and Cordova."},{"id":1,"title":"AngularJS in 50 Minutes","speaker":"LISA SMITH","time":"10:10am","room":"Ballroom B","description":"In this session, you'll learn everything you need to know to start building next-gen JavaScript applications using AngularJS."},{"id":2,"title":"Contributing to Apache Cordova","speaker":"JOHN SMITH","time":"11:10am","room":"Ballroom A","description":"In this session, John will tell you all you need to know to start contributing to Apache Cordova and become an Open Source Rock Star."},{"id":3,"title":"Mobile Performance Techniques","speaker":"JESSICA WONG","time":"3:10Pm","room":"Ballroom B","description":"In this session, you will learn performance techniques to speed up your mobile application."},{"id":4,"title":"Building Modular Applications","speaker":"LAURA TAYLOR","time":"2:00pm","room":"Ballroom A","description":"Join Laura to learn different approaches to build modular JavaScript applications."}]
```

I can't seem to get my head wrapped around why changing the http request to a local file does not work for the query performed in 'SessionCtrl'.

What changes need to be made so the detail view will work?

---

**UPDATE**

---

Following the suggestion from @ErnestoRendon I think I have made progress.

I changed the factory to look like this:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('data/sessions.json',{ }, {
        getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
      });
});
```

And the controller has been updated to look like this:

```
.controller('SessionCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Session) { 

    $scope.session = Session.getData({sessionId : $stateParams.sessionId});

    console.log($stateParams.sessionId); // This DOES log the correct option selected from the list
})
```

When leaving isArray set to false I get the same object/array error when `getData()` is called.  When I change isArray to "true" the error goes away but no data is returned to the UI. This is the error when setting that value to "false": http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array

In either scenario (isArray being "true" or "false") the correct sessionId will log to the console from the controller.

So while things appear to be better when setting isArray to "true," I'm still not getting data into the UI.

Comment: you can't perform .query call on json..? you need to have server side code to do query.

Comment: The call in the controller is a "get" (seen in the third code block in the post), not a query.  Notice the format of the $resource in the first two code blocks. That is the code I changed. Now I need the controller to be updated to work with the JSON file, not the http request.

Comment: I may have phrased the question wrong. I realize would need server side code to query a file.  What I'm trying to do is query/filter a JSON object based on the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that loads data from a JSON file similar to what you describe.

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('data/sessions.json',{ }, {
        getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
      });

});
```

Notice that isArray is set to false.

Comment: I tried that prior to posting and it had no effect on the expected outcome. Based on the error in the console (seen in the post) it appears that the "get" being called in the controller is to blame but I can't figure out why.

Comment: In my example i switch from the default "get" to "getData" secondly I noticed in your example

Comment: "return $resource('data/sessions.json');" is missing a paramters. 

$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options); 


https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get some of this. Do you have an example of what the parameters look would look like? I've been hacking at this all day and am close to giving up on all of this entirely - evidently it's over my head.

Also, here's the error I posted - follow this link to see the details: [link]https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array  I can't figure that out either.

Comment: Assuming you modified the get method to getData the controller should look something like..... 

.controller('SessionCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Session) {
    $scope.session = Session.getData();
})

Comment: The error message means the $resource parameters are not aligned properly

Comment: thanks - I've updated the post with the progress based on your suggestions. There is still no data returned to the UI but I believe it's closer than it was yesterday. Thanks for your help!